# Which AWS services for mobile app backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to figure out what AWS services I need for the mobile application I'm working on with my startup. The application we're working on should go into the app-/play-store later this year, so we need a "best-practice" solution for our case. It must be high scaleable so if there are thousands of requests to the server it should remain stable and fast. Also we maybe want to deploy a website on it.

Actually we are using Uberspace ([link](http://uberspace.de)) servers with an Node.js application and MongoDB running on it. Everything works fine, but for the release version we want to go with AWS. What we need is something we can run Node.js / MongoDB (or something similar to MongoDB) on and something to store images like profile pictures that can be requested by the user.

I have already read some informations about AWS on their website but that didn't help a lot. There are so many services and we don't know which of these fit our needs perfectly.

A friend told me to just use AWS EC2 for the Node.js server + MongoDB and S3 to store images, but on some websites I have read that it is better to use this architecture:

[image]

We would be glad if there is someone who can share his/her knowledge with us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To run code: you can use lambda, but be careful: the benefit you
  don't have to worry about server, the downside is lambda sometimes
  unreasonably slow. If you need it really fast then you need it on EC2
  with auto-scaling. If you tune it up properly it works like a charm.
- To store data: DynamoDB if you want it really fast (single digits
  milliseconds regardless of load and DB size) and according to best
  practices. It REQUIRES proper schema or will cost you a fortune,
  otherwise use MongoDB on EC2.
- If you need RDBMS then  RDS (benefits:
  scalability, availability, no headache with maintenance)
- Cache: they have both Redis and memcached.
- S3: to store static assets.
- I do not   suggest CloudFront, there are another CDN on market with better
  price/possibilities.
- API gateway: yes, if you have an API.
- Depending  on your app, you may need SQS.
- Cognito is a good service if you want    to authenticate your users at using google/fb/etc.
- CloudWatch: if    you're metric-addict then it's not for you, perhaps standalone EC2
  will be better. But, for most people CloudWatch is abcolutely OK.
- Create all necessary alarms (CPU overload etc).
- You should use roles
  to allow access to your S3/DB from lambda/AWS.
- You should not use the   root account but create a separate user instead.
- Create billing    alarm: you'll know if you're going to break budget.
- Create lambda    functions to backup your EBS volumes (and whatever else you may need   to backup). There's no problem if backup starts a second later, so
  Lambda is ok here.
- Run Trusted Adviser now and then.
- it'd be better for you to set it up using CloudFormation stack: you'll be able to deploy the same infrastructure with ease in another region if/when needed, also it's relatively easier to manage Infrastructure-as-a-code than when it built manually.

Comment: Thank your for the detailed answer! I'll follow your advices as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a very high scalable application, you may be need to use a serverless architecture with AWS lambda. 
There is a framework called serverless that helps you to manage and organize all your lambda function and put them behind AWS Gateway.
For the storage you can use AWS EC2 and install MongoDB or you can go with AWS DynamODB as your NoSql storage.
If you want a frontend, both web and mobile, you may be want to visit the react native approach.

I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I saw that EC2 is also high scaleable, so what is the benefit using AWS Lambda/Gateway compared to EC2 in our case? And why should we use EC2 for the storage when there is S3?

Comment: In with EC2 you must have ypur server always running and you pay for all the time you have your server up. With lambda there is no server running (at least the developer don't see and manage it) so you're only charged when the lambda is activate, so it is much cheaper. Besides, with EC2 you must have a load balancer and worry about it and configure it, in contrast, lambda escales automatically. I recommend you the AWS lambda in action book.

Comment: S3 is a storage for long term and static data as photos, files, ... but not for changing and dynamic data amd definetly not a storage for application data.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to read some more about AWS Lambda, but the storage that we need for images should be for long term. We want to provide images for some dynamic content in our app so the images need to be stored permanently. Is it still better to go with EC2 over S3?

Comment: You can have both because each one has its own purpose. In S3 you'll store static data such as images, but all the dynamic data such as user information, image metadata and other application data that will be updated or deleted must be in a database, SQL or NoSQL, in this case you've chosen MongoDB.